# How to convert mysql latin1 to utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I inherited a web system that I need to develop further.
The system seems to be created by someone who read two chapters of a PHP tutorial and thought he could code...

So... the webpage itself is in UTF8 and displays and inputs everything in it. The database tables have been created with UTF8 character set. But, in the config, there is "SET NAMES LATIN1". In other words, UTF8 encoded strings are populated into the database with forced latin1 coding.

Is there a way to convert this mess to actually store in utf8 and get rid of latin1?

I tried [this](http://alexking.org/blog/2008/03/06/mysql-latin1-utf8-conversion), but since the database table is set to utf8, this does not work. Also tried [this one](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/12/18/fixing-column-encoding-mess-in-mysql/) without success.

I maybe able to do this by reading all tables in PHP with latin1 encoding then write them back to a new database in utf8, but I want to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I managed to solve it by running updates on text fields like this:

```
UPDATE table SET title = CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(title USING latin1) USING binary) USING UTF8)
```

Comment: I tried this in my DB, but it cuts off every string at the position of the first umlaut or special character. Any ideas how to do it correctly?

Comment: If your field has correct UTF8 entries mixed in your table this will fail on those columns and get an 1300 error "Invalid utf8 character string". You can make the update row by row and skip over the rows that throw this error.

Comment: I have a solution for the 1300 error by adding an `IGNORE` clause. But this results in truncated text for example `¡Felicidades` will become `Felicidades`. Basically this string is already UTF8 and converting to latin1 back to utf8 causes data loss. You can add the following condition to skip over these rows if the raw bytes become changed `HEX(CONVERT(title USING latin1)) = HEX(CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(title USING latin1) USING BINARY) USING utf8))`

Answer (score 2):

The situation isn't as bad as you think it is, unless you already have lots of non-Roman characters (that is, characters that aren't representable in Latin-1) in your database already. Latin-1 is a proper subset of utf8. Your web app works in utf8 and your tables' contents are in utf8 as well. So there's no need to convert the tables.

So, try changing the `SET NAMES latin1` to `SET NAMES utf8`. It will probably solve your problem, by allowing your php program's connection to work with the same character set as the code on either end of the connection.

Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: The database contains a lot of hungarian strings with accents that couldn't be represented in latin1. The page works with SET NAMES latin1 and produces a mess if I change it to SET NAMES utf8.
I need to import a new table that contains the names of every city in Hungary. It is in proper UTF8 so if I access the DB as latin1 it will mess up this. So I either convert the current DB to proper UTF8 or convert the city list to forced latin1. I would prefer the former.

Answer (score -1):

Change column data type

to **VARBINARY**
and it's automatically convert the latin1 datas

Thank you guys.
I hope it's helpful.