# How do I remove Ã and � special character?

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.6, php-5.4

I have a website where the database mysql collation was in latin_1 and the php files were set with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`.

Now, the old website worked with PHP 5.4, I'm working with a 5.6 right now so I had to make lost of translations and changes. I'm still working on them, but I still have problems with speciale characters. I changed the db collation with UTF8mb4_unicode_ci and changed the charset of the files where it was written with `<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>`

I still get errors, seeing sometimes `Ã` for `é` and `�` for `'` . Is there something I'm missing? Did I do something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36531923/5542121
You most likely did not convert the content?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104083/convert-mysql-data-from-latin1-to-utf8

Comment: Unfortunately, I already did convert them, not just manually, but by apdating the entire table. I'll see what else I can try, thank you.

Comment: "updating" entire table sounds strange, u described that u changed the collation - changing the collation does usually not convert the content.

Comment: Mmh, doesn't this do the trick?
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: yes I think that does the trick. Last thing coming to my mind is setting the mysql connection from php to the proper charset: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php.

Comment: I should have done that too.. I'm checking if I did it correctly.