# How to convert MySQL database from Latin1 to Utf8

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have several tables in my database which are latin1, there are also several fields that are latin1 encoded, how can I check all the tables that are latin1 and convert them into utf8 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert mysql latin1 to utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529650/how-to-convert-mysql-latin1-to-utf8)

Comment: Be cautious of any conversion.  Test the technique, then try `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` with some utf8 character.